# python always returns if statement as true if i use or

Tags: python, loops

I'm relatively new to programming, and while i was making a simple scanner that runs a command whenever it finds a forward-slash (/) or a back-slash (\), it outputs things that (i think) it shouldn't be outputting.

here is the code:

```
loop = 0
a = 'm/es\s/a/ge'
while loop <= len(a)-1:
    if a[loop] == '/' or '\\':
        print ('found at: ' + str(loop))
    loop += 1
```

This outputs:

```
found at: 0
found at: 1
found at: 2
found at: 3
found at: 4
found at: 5
found at: 6
found at: 7
found at: 8
found at: 9
found at: 10
```

when it should only print anything 4 times (as there is only 4 slashes in the string)

I tried removing "or" along with the other possible value, and it did what it should, so the problem must be with the "or"

am I using "or" wrong? or is this something else?

EDIT:
I tried [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values), but that question is asking how to test multiple variables against a single value, while I need to know how to test a single variable against multiple possible values

Comment: You can't use `or` like that.

it's not `if a == 1 or 2` it's `if a == 1 or a == 2`

Or simpler : `if a in [1, 2]`

Comment: re-read the duplicate question, it applies to your `if a[loop] == '/' or '\\':` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

`if a[loop] == '/' or a[loop] == '\\'`

else the `'\\'` will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this in your condition statement:

> *If a[loop] =='/' or a[loop]=='\\':*